# I want to write a folder path from a textBox to a path specification as string

Tags: c#

In my Programm you can select a folder by pressing on a button.
The selected folder is written down in a textBox named txtZiel and i want to write this path into the following code to create a logfile.

Creating the log file is alreay workin but i have to write down the path so it is not automatically.

```
using (var logfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter($@"C:\Users\hmhatd.03\Desktop\Zielordner\{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}.txt"))
```

I want to replace `$@"C:\Users\hmhatd.03\Desktop\Zielordner\` with `txtZiel.Text`

Comment: `$@"{txtZiel.Text}\{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}.txt"`

Comment: You've already added the date to your filename, what is stopping you from replacing `C:\\Users\\hmhatd.03\\Desktop\\Zielordner` with `{txtZiel.Text}` in the same way?

Comment: `using (var logfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter($"{txtZiel.Text}{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}.txt"))`

Comment: I didnt use {} so it wasnt working but now it Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Better use the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) to create that name

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(txtZiel.Text, DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".txt");
using (var logfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
{
   ....
}
```

Notice that I have replaced the output format for DateTime.Today with a format that I am sure will not be problematic for the file system